# Including an image as part of a plot in a Shiny app deployed using http://www.shinyapps.io/?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I would like to include an image as part of a plot in a Shiny app, which I would like to deploy using http://www.shinyapps.io/.  As a very simple example, I have the following code, which gives me the desired results on my computer:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(plotOutput("myplot")))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(png)

image <- readPNG("image.png")

v1 <- c(1:20)
v2 <- c(1:20)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(v1,v2))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data, aes(v1,v2)) + 
    geom_point()+
    annotation_raster(image, xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=15, ymax=20)})}
```

However, I am having trouble with getting the app to work on shinyapps.io, specifically because the app is unable to open image.png.  I know that to use an image in a Shiny app, it should be saved in a folder called "www," which I have done, but it looks like this only works for images that are loaded by ui.R, not those loaded by server.R.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What happens if you do `readPNG("www/image.png")`?

Comment: Thanks @Carl, it works now.